# How to select last row of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following div:

```
<div data-object-id="dsOrders" class = "OrderList" >

    <div class="table-responsive m-y-1">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:110px;">ID</th>
                    <th style="width:110px;"> Order Date</th>
                </tr>

                <!-- FILTER ROW -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-search="OrderID" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-search="OrderDate" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr data-repeat data-active>
                    <td data-field="OrderID" class = "OrderID"></td>
                    <td data-field="OrderDate"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</div>
```

How do I make it select the last row of it with javascript or jquery? I've tried doing it like this

```
$("[.OrderList][tr:last]").focus();
```

But with no success

Comment: $('#yourtableid tr:last').attr('id'); this will give you id of last row.... or try this $("#tableid").find("tr").last();

Comment: To make a `tr` focusable, you'll need to add a `tabindex` attribute.

Comment: There's no default action for selecting a row. You have to set f.e. its background color when clicking on, or other way getting a reference to a row.

Comment: in this case the row is made selectable with `data-active` attribute

Comment: `data-active` doesn't make a row selectable without some extra code, which you're not showing (a library/framework?). `data-*` is just a way to add custom attributes to elements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
.OrderList >.table > tbody > tr:last-child { background:#ff0000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#yourtableid tr:last').attr('id');
```

or this:

```
$("#TableId").find("tr").last();
```

**Hope this if helpful :)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourtableid tr:last').attr('id').focus();
```

or

```
$('#yourtableid tr:last')[0].focus();
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($(".OrderList table tr:last").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-object-id="dsOrders" class = "OrderList" >

    <div class="table-responsive m-y-1">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:110px;">ID</th>
                    <th style="width:110px;"> Order Date</th>
                </tr>

                <!-- FILTER ROW -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-search="OrderID" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-search="OrderDate" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr data-repeat data-active>
                    <td data-field="OrderID" class = "OrderID"></td>
                    <td data-field="OrderDate"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($(".OrderList tr").last().html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-object-id="dsOrders" class = "OrderList" >

    <div class="table-responsive m-y-1">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:110px;">ID</th>
                    <th style="width:110px;"> Order Date</th>
                </tr>

                <!-- FILTER ROW -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-search="OrderID" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-search="OrderDate" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr data-repeat data-active>
                    <td data-field="OrderID" class = "OrderID"></td>
                    <td data-field="OrderDate"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code You can achieve it by:

```
$('#first table:last tr:last')
```